# SharePoint Web Page AutoSize

Tags: html, sharepoint, autosize

What is a code I could put in the Edit Source to set the width and height of the SharePoint site?

```
<style type="text/css">

body {

width: 100%;

height: 100%;

}

</style>
```

The above script is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The following style for your reference.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
#s4-workspace{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
</style>
```

In SharePoint site, I suggest you create a Responsive Master Page to achieve your requirement.

Refer to the solution here: [SharePoint Branding - Responsive Master Page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Branding-e73dffa0)

Comment: How do I use that code to include the top, center, and footer of the body section? When I placed that code in, it only displayed the top of the SharePoint site, not the remainder.

Comment: Refer to the article here: https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Web-Cast-Responsive-UI-Package-for-SharePoint-2013-and-2016/player